# Securely copy a file from a server and sudo with password?

Tags: bash

in a bash script I need to copy /etc/passwd from a remote server but the sshd services do not allow root login (no surprise since it's the default).

So normally I would have used something like sshpass 'passwd'  scp user@server:/etc/passwd /local/system   to get the script to login and copy,  however since the user can not be root, I am not sure how to do this.  I have SUDO access but it requires the login password when issued?

Has anyone done this ?   basically login cat or copy the passwd file with sudo asking for the password ?

Comment: Why do you need to be root to copy `/etc/passwd`? It's generally world readable.

Comment: You don't need to be root to read /etc/passwd. Do you need root access for something else?

Comment: Is the script supposed to be interactive, (a human can type a password on a keyboard) or not ?

Comment: Good question guys, the shadow file is needed as well and that is protected from a non-root view.  The user only should have to put their user/password in once and then a set of servers will be processed. Hence the script is really NOT interactive.

Comment: OK, I think I figured something out.  So I will answer this question after some testing ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supporting function:

```
    pipewrap(){
        echo $1  # which is password
        local lockFile=$2;
        while true; do
            # The function will exit when output pipe is closed, 
            if [ ! -e $lockFile ]; then
                return 0
            fi
            # i.e., the ssh
            read -t 1 line
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
                # successfully read
                echo $line
            fi
        done
    }
```

Run ssh + sudo command funtion:

```
    run_ssh_sudo () {
        local REMOTECOMPUTER=$1;
        local PASSWORD=$2;
        local REMOTECOMMAND=$3;
        local ARGUMENTS=$4;
        local REMOTEUSER=$5;

        sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" "${SSH_COMMAND}" "$REMOTEUSER@$REMOTECOMPUTER" "sudo -K"

        local lockFile=`mktemp`
        eval pipewrap '$PASSWORD' '$lockFile' | (sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" "${SSH_COMMAND}" "$REMOTEUSER@$REMOTECOMPUTER" "sudo -S '$REMOTECOMMAND' $ARGUMENTS"; rm "$lockFile")

    }
```